# How to draw an arrow from one table's row to another table' row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two tables. When I drag first tables row to another table's row (clone of row in first table ). what I need to do here is draw an arrow that this row is cloned to this row. It would be great this can be done using canvas.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this plugin -> http://www.openstudio.fr/Library-for-simple-drawing-with.html?lang=fr uses canvas on IE

It allows you to draw lines within a DIV :

```
$("#example1").drawLine(0, 0, 220, 45);
```

where #example1 is the div id. You could grab the coords at the start of your drag and again and the end and draw a line between the 2 points.